# Type an object key value according an existing object' keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have an object

```
const First = {
  john: "whatever",
  doe: "whatever-whatever",
  Fulan: "whatever-whatever-whatever"
}
```

I'd like to create a typed "myStrongType" object with the following values that ensures the key is from First and the value is the key

```
const Second: myStrongType = {
      john: "john",
      doe: "doe",
      Fulan: "Fulan"
    }
```

and my linter would recognize an error when I do something like that

```
 const Third: myStrongType = {
          john: "doe",
          doe: "doe",
          Fulan: "john"
        }
```

The best I did is with `keyof typeof First` and then type

```
Second: Record<
  keyof typeof First,
  keyof typeof First
>
```

But it's not enough :)

Comment: possibly: [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRzd7w) `type StrongType<T> = {[K in keyof T]: K;}`

Comment: Thanks it works fine =>
 type myStrongType = {
  [P in keyof typeof First]: P
}

Comment: `type myStrongType = { [key in keyof typeof First]: key };`